# Swig exception in Python director class

Tags: python, c++, exception, swig

I'm wrapping some classes using Swig directors in Python.
Each of my class methods returns a MyError class. What happens is, once I derive a python class from one of my C++ and I forget to return the MyError() object but I return None of "pass" or I forget to return anything, my software crashes in the default constructor of the MyError class through a read access violation, and I'm not able to track this exception through a try/catch block.

What is the correct way in Swig to handle such kind of situations ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] that illustrates the crash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Section 36.5.4 Exception unrolling](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn36) in the SWIG documentation:

> With directors routing method calls to Python, and proxies routing them to C++, the handling of exceptions is an important concern. By default, the directors ignore exceptions that occur during method calls that are resolved in Python. To handle such exceptions correctly, it is necessary to temporarily translate them into C++ exceptions. This can be done with the %feature("director:except") directive. The following code should suffice in most cases:

```
%feature("director:except") {
    if ($error != NULL) {
        throw Swig::DirectorMethodException();
    }
}
```

> This code will check the Python error state after each method call from a director into Python, and throw a C++ exception if an error occurred. This exception can be caught in C++ to implement an error handler. Currently no information about the Python error is stored in the Swig::DirectorMethodException object, but this will likely change in the future.
>
> It may be the case that a method call originates in Python, travels up to C++ through a proxy class, and then back into Python via a director method. If an exception occurs in Python at this point, it would be nice for that exception to find its way back to the original caller. This can be done by combining a normal %exception directive with the director:except handler shown above. Here is an example of a suitable exception handler:

```
%exception {
    try { $action }
    catch (Swig::DirectorException &e) { SWIG_fail; }
}
```

> The class Swig::DirectorException used in this example is actually a base class of Swig::DirectorMethodException, so it will trap this exception. Because the Python error state is still set when Swig::DirectorMethodException is thrown, Python will register the exception as soon as the C wrapper function returns.

**Example**

Here's an example `test.i` that illustrates the technique:

```
%module test

%module(directors="1") test
%feature("director");

%feature("director:except") {
    if ($error != NULL) {
        throw Swig::DirectorMethodException();
    }
}

%exception {
    try { $action }
    catch (Swig::DirectorException &e) { SWIG_fail; }
}

%inline %{
    class MyError {
        int m_n;
    public:
        MyError(int n = 0) : m_n(n) {}
        ~MyError() {}
        int get() const { return m_n; }
    };

    class Demo {
    public:
        Demo() {}
        virtual ~Demo() {}
        virtual MyError test() { return MyError(5); }
    };

    int func(Demo* d) { return d->test().get(); }
%}
```

After swigging and compiling, a demo:

```
>>> import test
>>> d=test.Demo()  # default class implementation
>>> test.func(d)   # Call virtual method in a C++ test function.
5
```

The above worked normally.  Below overrides incorrectly:

```
>>> class Demo2(test.Demo):  # New class
...  def test(self):         # Override virtual function
...   return 7               # But don't return a MyError object.
...
>>> d=Demo2()
>>> test.func(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: SWIG director type mismatch in output value of type 'MyError'
```

That caught the exception and returned a useful exception.  Below overrides correctly:

```
>>> class Demo2(test.Demo):
...  def test(self):
...   return test.MyError(7)
...
>>> d=Demo2()
>>> test.func(d)
7
```

Comment: completely missed this part. Nice answer!

Comment: additional note, this work now until I return some kind of object, but if I type pass instead of the return, the code still crashes. Any advice ?

Comment: @LeonardoBernardini Late reply.  I forgot about this, but a recent upvote made me read it again.  The code is crashing because it is a structured exception (SEH) instead of a C++ exception.  With the Microsoft compiler, compile with `/EHa` and you can catch them directly via `catch(...)` or convert to a C++ exception using `_set_se_translator`.  See [this MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/exception-handling-differences?view=msvc-160).